# Discard pile should face up or down?

Tags: arctic-scavengers

In Arctic Scavengers, should the players' discard pile face up or down? It seems that the rulebook does not specify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discard pile should go face down. The rules are not super-clear about this, but in the "Sample Round", it says:

> The player draws 1 card from the 
>   junkyard (dig of 1) and places that card face-down in her discard pile.

You can find a discussion about this rule [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1201393/discard-pile-goes-face-down-right).